# Windows IIS 8.5 new website permission denied

Tags: php, windows, iis, permissions, iis-8.5

I would like to ask for help about setting new website on Windows server IIS 8.5

I have two version of PHP on my server, 5.4.9 and 5.6.2.2. Both of them are working correctly. MySQL server is working too. I have created new site in IIS, given all permissions for IIS_IUSRS, but when I want to run webpage, I always get Permission denied for fopen() function. I am using czech PHP framework Nette and it needs write permissions for some folders. Without that it cannot work. But I am not able to do any change to fix it. Site folder is right in C:\inetpub\ folder. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

I have gone through many of tutorials and issues here on StackOverflow, but no of those advices have worked.

One more question to the end, do you have any detailed tutorial how to properly set up new PHP website in IIS 8.5? All the time when I fix something, another thing is wrong. And according to those tutorials I have found it looks too quick and easy.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What File are you trying to `fopen()` ?

Comment: It is generated file for framework. It is inner cache file. Maybe it will help if I write the error message I got:
fopen(C:\inetpub\website\temp\cache/_Nette.RobotLoader/_f093448321925bc685b925c337cda4bc): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Check the App Pool running the site and if its the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` then and make sure `IIS APPPOOL\<App Pool Name>` has access to that folder `C:\inetpub\website\temp\cache`. if its a different user listed under `Identity` for the app pool make sure that Login has access

Comment: My selected AppPool website has Identity NetworkService. I gave him the rights to the folders that I need, but it is still the same problem, Nothing changed. Do I have to create some new user login to the system to make it work?

Comment: Since you're using `Network Service` make sure the "user" `Network Service` and `IUSR` have access to the folder as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it didn't help. Right now I have set Create, Write and Delete permissions to user **IIS AppPool\website**, **IUSR**, **Network Service** and **IIS_IUSRS group**. I really don't know who else I should give permissions to write into this folder. I am just wondering, if there might be another bug or if I just made some mistake in setting the website or server up. What do you think? Thanks for help

**EDIT:**

So I finally found the solution of this problem. There was one important user, that didn't have access rights to this folder. It was group **Users**. I gave the rights and it is working.